# Python [Pandas/docx]: Merging two rows based on common name

Tags: python, pandas, docx, python-docx

I am trying to write a script using docx-python and pandas in Python3 which perform following action:

1. Take input from csv file
2. Merge common value of Column C and add each value into docx
3. Export docx

My raw csv is as below:

```
SN. Name    Instance    Severity
1   Name1   file1:line1 CRITICAL
2   Name1   file2:line3 CRITICAL
3   Name2   file1:line1 Low
4   Name2   file1:line3 Low
and so on...
```

and i want my docx outpur as:
`
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xNc0.png

I am not able to figure it out how can i filter "Instances" based on "Name" using pandas and later print then into docx.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service. You are supposed to provide in your question your own code attempt, with related details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will select the relevant columns,group by based on 'Name' and 'Severity' and add Instances together

```
df2 = df[["Name","Instance","Severity"]]
df2["Instance"] = df2.groupby(['Name','Severity'])['Instance'].transform(lambda x: '\n'.join(x))
```

Finally, remove the duplicates and transform to get the desired output

```
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()
df2 = df2.T
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly fine. df2 = df2.T was not working initially but with little changes in my code, I managed to make it work.